# Why would Microsoft SQL Server start throwing deadlock exceptions for one table when it never has before?

Tags: sql-server

A few days we started having exceptions thrown quite frequently in one of our applications.  These all are of the form:

```
Exception : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
Transaction (Process ID 66) was deadlocked on lock resources with 
another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. 
Rerun the transaction.
```

Some interesting facts:

- These exceptions all occur for a specific update on a single table.
- Due to the way things occur in the system, it is often that a whole bunch of these updates will be triggered in different threads essentially simultaneously.  However, for as long as the system has been running this behavior has never caused a problem (as far as anyone knows ,  and we'd know, the exception is cluttering the log significantly), SQL server has properly handled this in a queued fashion with no lock issue.
- Plenty of other update queries will occur against other tables simultaneously, creating the same circumstances, but not causing issues.
- This is SQL Server 2005
- It is claimed nothing has changed with server, database, schema, or table configuration.

However, I doubt the last claim is true.  What kinds of things could be changed about server config that would change how the server deals with simultaneous updates?

Comment: Doesn't take a big change to a query or to data to cause a deadlock - no change to schema / config etc. required. Really tough to provide any input to you whatsoever without a deadlock graph. Have you captured one of these? Do you know how? [Some good material here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126/what-are-the-main-causes-of-deadlocks-and-can-they-be-prevented).

Comment: Oh we haven't heard that one before. Nothing has changed, it just went wrong. Not going to be able help without knowing what deadlocked it.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I know, right?

Comment: Just realized this question probably belongs on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ but I didn't actually know that existed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like this can happen if tables become fragmented or if statistics become stale over time. Did someone drop an index perhaps? See also [Proactive Deadlock Notifications](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/MSSQLServerAdmin/proactive-deadlock-notifications) to see how you can get notified when deadlocks happen

Comment: The index is an interesting thought.  It turns out on this server the pkey is missing for this table (field is there, but not a pkey).  I've changed it to a pkey and the error hasn't happened now for a bit... will watch.